# Splunk: Stats from multiple events and expecting one combined output

Tags: splunk

I have below events

event_a has `time_a` and `MAS_A` fields

event_b has `time_b` and `MAS_B` fields

event_c has `time_c` and `MAS_C` fields

```
sourcetype="app" eventtype in (event_a,event_b,event_c) 
| stats avg(time_a) as "Avg Response Time" BY MAS_A 
| eval Avg Response Time=round('Avg Response Time',2)
```

Output I am getting from above search is two fields `MAS_A` and `Avg Response Time`

I am trying to get this for `event_b` and `event_c` as well in same search SPL and expecting final output with two fields only 
`MAS_A_B_C` and `Avg Response Time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Some sample events may help with your query.

```
sourcetype="app" eventtype in (event_a,event_b,event_c) 
| eval time_value=coalesce(time_a, time_b, time_c)
| eval MAS_value =coalesce(MAS_A,MAS_B,MAS_C)
| stats avg(time_value) as "Avg Response Time" BY MAS_value 
| eval Avg Response Time=round('Avg Response Time',2)
```

Comment: Worked Great. I think coalesce in SQL and in Splunk is totally different. What if i have NULL value and want to display NULL also

Comment: Can you check my other question too that is similar to this one. but i am expecting stats for every event MAS filed as separate column

Comment: coalesce will return the first NULL value, so if you need to show it, coalesce probably isnt applicable in that use-case. I will look at the next issue shortly